# DecimalFormat rounding mode: Rounding 0.165 (HALF_EVEN) to 2 decimal places rounds up to 0.17?

Tags: java

Here is the code:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        formatNumber("##.##", 0.125);
        formatNumber("##.##", 0.165);

    }

    public static void formatNumber(String pattern, double value) {
        formatter.applyPattern(pattern);
        String formattedNumber = formatter.format(value);
        System.out.println("Number:" + value + ", Pattern:" +
                pattern + ", Formatted Number:" +
                formattedNumber);
    }
```

I got this output.

```
Number:0.125, Pattern:##.##, Formatted Number:0,12
Number:0.165, Pattern:##.##, Formatted Number:0,17
```

I know that by default it uses HALF_EVEN rounding mode.
For instance, 5.5 would be rounded to 6, and 6.5 to 6.
But how is that rule applied if for instance I have more than 1 digit after the decimal point. I don't get it. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rounding rule is still applied correctly, but it doesn't appear so at first.  This is displayed as "0.17" because 0.165 cannot be represented precisely as a floating-point `double`; the value of the representation is slightly above 0.165.

The number `0.125` can be represented exactly (2<sup>-3</sup>), so it correctly rounds down to `0.12` for display.

But the number `0.165` only appears that it should be rounded down.

```
System.out.println(Long.toHexString(Double.doubleToLongBits(0.165)));
```

The hexadecimal representation is

```
3fc51eb851eb851f
```

The mantissa is the last 13 hex digits, which establish the repeating hexadecimal "51eb8", but the last hex digit is rounded up to "f", so the value of the floating-point representation is slightly greater than the actual mathematical number 0.165.  Because of this, it's rounded up for display as "0.17".